# Dotnet Restore Failed on Build Server

Tags: c#, jenkins, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a little dotnet core application and want to build it on jenkins.
In order to make it happen, ive installed dotnet core on the build slave.

Locally i can restore with the same command successfuly (even on my mac)

```
dotnet restore --configfile .nuget/NuGet.Config
```

On the build server the restore fails for one package.

```
Started by user jenkins
Building remotely on 2c3bff31e594 in workspace /root/workspace/Test
Cloning the remote Git repository
...
+ dotnet restore --configfile .nuget/NuGet.Config

Welcome to .NET Core!
---------------------
...
log  : Installing System.Runtime 4.1.0-rc2-24027.
log  : Installing System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1-rc2-24027.
log  : Installing System.Reflection.Extensions 4.0.1-rc2-24027.
...
log  : Restoring packages for /root/workspace/Test/test/Test.DataAccess.Tests/project.json...
log  : Failed to download package from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/remotion.linq/2.1.1/remotion.linq.2.1.1.nupkg'.
log  : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

The strange thing here is, that if i hit the url
"https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/remotion.linq/2.1.1/remotion.linq.2.1.1.nupkg" link from the log, the package is their.

Answer (score 0):

probably a firewall or any other local setting

probably firewall. id install [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) on the computer and look what is the exact request

add fiddler as nuget porxy like this:

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings#proxy-settings

```
Proxy settings
section: config
keys: http_proxy, http_proxy.user, http_proxy.password and no_proxy.

Allows you to set the proxy settings to be used while connecting to your NuGet feed. More details here.

This key can be added using NuGet.exe Config -Set command.

It can also be set via environment variables http_proxy and no_proxy. http_proxy should be specified in the format http://[username]:[password]@proxy.com whereas no_proxy should be a comma-separated list of domains to bypass the proxy server.

Note
The "http_proxy.password" key value is encrypted before storing in the nuget.config file. Hence it can not be added manually by directly updating the config file.
```