# Google Cloud - 404 for a Request from an Instance

Tags: curl, nuget, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an instance (vm) on google cloud compute. No i have the problem that if i ssh in one machine i cant access some resources (outgoing).

I get a 404 - Not Found.

E.g.

Success

```
$ curl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137875/dotnet-restore-failed-on-build-server
```

Fails (404)

```
$ curl https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/remotion.linq/2.1.1/remotion.linq.2.1.1.nupkg
```

How to fix this?

### Update

The output of `curl -v` is

```
curl -v https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/remotion.linq/2.1.1/remotion.linq.2.1.1.nupkg
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 68.232.34.200...
* Connected to api.nuget.org (68.232.34.200) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
> Host: api.nuget.org
* Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=*.vo.msecnd.net
*        start date: 2016-08-20 21:42:56 GMT
*        expire date: 2018-04-20 21:42:56 GMT
*        subjectAltName: api.nuget.org matched
*        issuer: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; OU=Microsoft IT; CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /v3-flatcontainer/remotion.linq/2.1.1/remotion.linq.2.1.1.nupkg HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: api.nuget.org
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 07:38:40 GMT
* Server ECAcc (lcy/1D73) is not blacklisted
< Server: ECAcc (lcy/1D73)
< Content-Length: 345
< 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
                <title>404 - Not Found</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
        </body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host api.nuget.org left intact
```

Comment: After waiting the whole day doing other things, it is now working.